# How to back up and restore a large mysql database WITHOUT dumping

Tags: mysql, linux, database-backups

I have a large database that contains some binary data.

As a result, I can run mysqldump but it always results in a bad dump file.

What is the easiest way to back up and restore without dumping on linux systems?

Comment: Can you give an example of the `mysqldump` command you use?

Comment: did you try your dump with this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_hex-blob ? may help

Comment: if the above does not help you may want to check out this one: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html